# How can I set up UIDatePicker to always UTC time and date, disregard daylight savings time

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker

UIDatePicker
I want to set up UIDatePicker to have always UTC time and date, ignore any local time and Daylight savings time. In my app UIDatePicker after 31 March 2019 if I will set time 02:00 in text field it will show 03:00.

```
`func createDatePicker()  {
    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker?.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    datePicker?.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")! as TimeZone

    datePicker?.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

    datePicker?.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
    datePicker?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)

datePicker?.minimumDate = Date.calculateDate(day: 1, month: 1, year: 2019, hour: 0, minute: 0)
datePicker?.maximumDate = Date.calculateDate(day: 1, month: 1, year: 2020, hour: 0, minute: 0)




    // create toll bar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    toolBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque

    //add done botton on this tool bar
    let doneBotton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(doneDateClicked))
    toolBar.setItems([doneBotton], animated: true)
    doneBotton.style = .done
    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar


    dateTextField.inputView = datePicker
}`
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following function to get the offset you might need to apply to correct for the daylight saving time.

```
datePicker?.timeZone.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: Date)
```

> Returns the daylight saving time offset for a given date.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **date:** The date to use for the calculation. The default value is the current date.

[See Apple Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293268-daylightsavingtimeoffset)